# Setters and getters for Array of LinkedList

Tags: java

I have a class that called `Entries` that holds my constructor along with its getters and setters.

In a new class, I have :

```
private LinkedList<Entry>[] Entries = new LinkedList[26];

public void changeNumber(String number, String numberChange) {
  for (int i = 0; i < myEntries.length; i++){


        if (myEntries[i].getNumber().equals(number)){
            myEntries[i].setNumber(numberChange);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am receiving errors for my setters and getters. This does not happen when I use a straight array or straight `LinkedList`, as I've already got this method working for those two in two different classes.

The error messages I'm receiving for both are

> The method getNumber() is undefined for the type LinkedList
>   and The method getNumber() is undefined for the type LinkedList

I don't see why they're undefined as when I've tried doing the same method for a straight `Array` and a pure `LinkedList`, they've handled it fine and functioned properly.

If anyone has any suggestions, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `myEntries[i].get(listIndex).getNumber()`, no?

Comment: `getNumber()` should be a method for the object `Entry` (not `LinkedList`).  You should really look at the differences between an array and a LinkedList because you're using an array of LinkedLists (and possibly redundantly).

Comment: Is the real name of your variable `Entries` or `myEntries` ?

Answer (score 2):

Pay close attention to the data type you're iterating over.  Because `myEntries` is defined as a `LinkedList<Entry>[]`, you're pulling out an individual `LinkedList<Entry>` when you iterate over the array.

It really seems like you *don't* want the array; instead, just iterate over the list elements directly:

```
LinkedList<Entry> myEntries = new LinkedList<>();

for(Entry entry : myEntries) {
    if(entry.equals(number) {
        // logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

myEntries[i] returns a LinkedList this doesnt have the setNumber method. You need to get the Entry out of the list and then invoke these methods.

myEntries[i].get(index).setNumber(); or myEntries[i].getFirst().setNumber(); etc

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call your accessors/mutators (`getNumber()` & `setNumber`) on the `LinkedList` instance and since there is no such methods for the `LinkedList` you will have the reported error.

So either get access to some `LinkedList` item with `get()` method that will return an `Entry` object on which you can call your setter and getter:

```
public void changeNumber(String number, String numberChange) {
  int index = 0; //not sure what this index should be in your case
  for (int i = 0; i < myEntries.length; i++){
    if (myEntries[i].get(index).getNumber().equals(number)){
      myEntries[i].get(index).setNumber(numberChange);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Or better if you don't need the `LinkedList`, may be it is worth dropping you design and only create an `Array` of `Entry`:

```
private Entry[] entries = new Entry[26];
```

Then your `changeNumber()` method will be eligible:

```
public void changeNumber(String number, String numberChange) {
  for (int i = 0; i < myEntries.length; i++){
    if (myEntries[i].getNumber().equals(number)){
      myEntries[i].setNumber(numberChange);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```